SQL Joins returning results from one T-SQL Query but not another
I have coded two T-SQL queries which are executed on Databricks using Databricks SQL.
The first query returns results of 144 rows:
144 Rows Returned
    SELECT DISTINCT
      PSTT.TransactionTypeID
    FROM basedrd.TransactionType PSTT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN basedrd.PMSTransaction ST
      ON PSTT.TransactionType = ST.TransactionType
    WHERE PSTT.TransactionSource = 'Pershing'
    OR (PSTT.TransactionSource = '')
    AND (ST.SEDOL = 'CASH'
          AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 1
          OR ST.SEDOL <> 'CASH'
          AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 0)

The second query doesn't return any rows
No Rows returned
SELECT DISTINCT
  PSTT.TransactionTypeID
FROM basedrd.PMSTransaction ST
LEFT OUTER JOIN basedrd.TransactionType PSTT
  ON PSTT.TransactionType = ST.TransactionType
    AND (PSTT.TransactionSource = 'Pershing'
      OR PSTT.TransactionSource = '')
    AND (ST.SEDOL = 'CASH'
      AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 1
      OR ST.SEDOL <> 'CASH'
      AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 0)

The stranges thing is that if I execute the same code on our SQL Server I get 145 rows returned onf the first query
145 rows returned
SELECT DISTINCT
  PSTT.TransactionTypeID
FROM dbo.TransactionType PSTT
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PMSTransaction ST
  ON PSTT.TransactionType = ST.TransactionType
WHERE PSTT.TransactionSource = 'Pershing'
OR (PSTT.TransactionSource = '')
AND (ST.SEDOL = 'CASH'
      AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 1
      OR ST.SEDOL <> 'CASH'
      AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 0)

And whereas I wasn't getting any rows returned with the second query on Databricks above on our SQL Server I get 46 rows returned.
SELECT DISTINCT
  PSTT.TransactionTypeID
FROM dbo.PMSTransaction ST
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TransactionType PSTT
  ON PSTT.TransactionType = ST.TransactionType
    AND (PSTT.TransactionSource = 'Pershing'
      OR PSTT.TransactionSource = '')
    AND (ST.SEDOL = 'CASH'
      AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 1
      OR ST.SEDOL <> 'CASH'
      AND PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 0)

The only difference between the query executed on Databricks SQL and SQL Server is the database name(schema)  SQL Server is dbo, whereas databricks is basedrd.

Your local copy of TransactionType or PMSTransaction was modified after you uploaded to databricks. Upload again or resync and see if they are still out of sync.

Take a close look at the parentheses you have in the various conditions. They are not equivalent. Note also that the on clause for a left outer join correctly handles null values from the right-hand table, but references to that table in a where clause must explicitly allow for null values to avoid converting the outer join to an inner join.

@BartMcEndree, thanks for getting in touch. I did a count on both tables in databricks and sql server and they both matched

@HABO, thanks for reaching out. You observation seems to be plausible, however I don't fully understand what you're getting at

The first (144 Rows Returned) is PSTT.TransactionSource = 'Pershing' or <big and/or condition>. The second (No Rows Returned) is (PSTT.TransactionSource = 'Pershing' OR PSTT.TransactionSource = '') and <different big and/or condition>. Think of or as + and and as * and apply the usual rules for arithmetic operator precedence: * before + unless overridden by parentheses. Is the part about outer vs inner joins clear? Using  to look for where clause converts outer join to inner join should clear that up.

Hi @HABO, I will do a little research as you suggested. In the meantime, can you answer why I'm getting differing results from SQL Server to Databricks - even though they're working from the same tables?

When your filters are different don't you think you might see a difference in the number of rows returned?

@shawnt00, I agree, but I'm running the same filters, but just on different engines ... ie. SQL Server and Databricks

Why are you reversing the direction of the join between the two queries?

“I have coded two T-SQL queries which are executed on Databricks using Databricks SQL.” Databricks SQL and T-SQL are two different dialects, and expecting them to behave exactly the same way is indicative you have a pretty fundamental flaw in your understanding of this fact. Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that the two are interchangeable? How were you able to verify that the tables themselves contain exactly the same data? Data types between the two also don’t overlap all that much at all, which can change the way your JOINs work.

Just to clarify, I had thought you were using parentheses differently across queries. I'm glad you made progress.

It appears that your data doesn't match up. A query like should help confirm that the values don't line up as expected:
with data as (
    select
        case when PSTT.TransactionSource = 'Pershing' then 'Pershing'
             when PSTT.TransactionSource = ''         then 'Blank'
             when ST.TransactionType is not null      then
                 case when PSTT.TransactionType is not null then 'Other' else 'Null' end
             else 'Unmatched Row' end as TransactionSource,
        case when ST.SEDOL = 'CASH' then 'Cash'
             when ST.SEDOL is null  then 'Null'
             else 'Other' end as SEDOL,
        case when PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 0     then '0'
             when PSTT.IsCashTransaction = 1     then '1'
             when PSTT.IsCashTransaction is null then 'Null'
             else 'Other' end as IsCashTransaction
    from <SRC>.PMSTransaction ST left outer join <SRC>.TransactionType PSTT
        on PSTT.TransactionType = ST.TransactionType
)
select TransactionSource, SEDOL, IsCashTransaction, count(*)
from data
group by TransactionSource, SEDOL, IsCashTransaction
order by TransactionSource, SEDOL, IsCashTransaction;


@shawntoo, thanks for reaching. I implemented your code, and indeed the data didn't match. Thank you
